# Checkbox Behavior, in directive or in controller?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I implemented a behavior of master checkbox (in table header) and entry checkboxes (in table rows), here's my html:

```
<div class="container main" ng-controller="ParamCtrl as param">

    .
    .
    .
    <form>

        <thead>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="param.masterCheckBox" ng-click="param.clickMaster()" />
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="entry in param.entries track by $index">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="parameter.checked" ng-click="param.click($index)" />
            </tr>
        </tbody>


    </form>

</div>
```

The behavior of master checkbox and row checkboxes was implemented inside a controller (not a controller in a directive). Here is my js file (since this is working, I removed the logic inside the functions already):

```
app.controller('ParamCtrl', function() {

    this.function1 = function() {...};
    this.function2 = function () {...};
    .
    .
    .
    this.clickMaster = function(){...};
    this.click = function(index){...};


});
```

I've read many times that DOM manipulations within the controller is not advisable, but should be inside a directive. I'm still not yet fully understanding the directive concepts in AngularJS. I'm not so sure either if checkbox behavior falls under DOM, kindly verify if putting this in a controller is just right. How do I implement a directive version of clickMaster and click functions if putting these in controllers is wrong (or bad practice)?

app.controller('ParamCtrl', function() {...}) that uses *this* works just fine. However, whenever I alter the controller with

```
app.controller('ParamCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {...}])
```

or

```
app.controller('ParamCtrl', function($scope) {...}])
```

and replace all instances of *this* with *$scope* in the source code, the code is not working anymore. In my debugging in Chrome Dev Tools, $scope (in both cases of alteration) has value ChildScope. In code examples I have seen, they would normally use *$scope* instead of *this*. Could someone explain why is it working with *this* and not with *$scope*?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the only thing you do in those functions is setting values on your model so the checkboxes are either checked or unchecked? In that case your approach is valid.

DOM manipulation means you are changing the structure of your DOM tree (the model behind HTML) from inside JavaScript. Examples of DOM manipulation include creating new DOM elements (with `document.createElement(<element name>)´ and using a query selector to retrieve a DOM element (either with jQuery or with built ins like`document.getElementById();´

The idea is to restrict DOM manipulation to directives as these are intended to enhance your HTML and hence this is the semantically correct place to put them (there are other reasons like avoiding memory leaks).

Comment: The code inside the controller is a bit lengthy and messy. Is it possible also to place this checkbox behavior in a factory (or service) injected to the controller in order to do some refactoring? Even if that is possible, is it a good practice?